# cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I've got a `CursorAdapter` that I swap data into, from inside the `onLoadFinished()` callback. Immediately after, I also need to use the same cursor for multiple other `CursorAdapters` (only 1 illustrated below). The problem is that after the cursor `data` gets swaped into the original `CursorAdapter`, I get the below error. If I `getCursor()` from the original `CursorAdapter` later in the app, it works without any errors. Why is that ? Is the `swapCursor()` asynchronous or what ? I thought so initialy, but after I tried to set the `data` `Cursor` directly to the other `CursorAdapters` it still have me the error. So what gives ? Any ideas ?

```
   @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
         mAccountsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
         // create new cursor adapter
         Cursor cursor = new CursorWrapper(mAccountsCursorAdapter.getCursor());
         mNewAccountsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
```

Error below:

```
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:135)
            at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
            at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1141)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently because of some issues in the code, the `onLoadFinished()` callback was called twice at almost the same time, which probably didn't have a good impact on the `data` `Cursor`. So double check your code if you encounter this issue.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more in depth? What might cause `onLoadFinished()` to be called twice in a row? I am dealing with the same symptoms at the moment.

Comment: I really can't remember the reason why onLoadFinished() was called twice in my use case back then. And even if I could remember, it might not be the same reason as your use case. These sort of issues are really dependent of each implementation, thus they can vary a lot, that's probably why I haven't detailed the actual cause back then. In retrospect, I might just as well added the details. But unfortunately, the time has passed. For your case, try and debug your code using the built in AS debugger, I've found it to be extremely useful in cases such as this one.

Comment: Yeah, been debugging for a while now, seams like my case might be related to where I call `initLoader()`. It looks like it does not like that i call it again after an orientation change.

Comment: Ah! I found the bug, and I'll just put the solution as a quick comment in case anybody else stumbles upon something similar. So the loaders seem to stay active even though activities and fragments might restart, in my case due to an orientation change. So before one calls `initLoader()` one needs to call `getLoader()` to check that the loader is not already running. =)